# Split or merge cells in Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I have to make a table in which some rows are split and some cells are merged.

For example: In the first column I have two rows, but in second column each row is divided into several small rows. So, one row in the first column turns into several rows in the second column.

Looks as follows:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnMAB.gif]

However, I can't find how to split or merge cells in Silverlight [datagrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189058(v=vs.95).aspx). Do I have to create my own control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer. 
For each cell where I have to split cell into several rows, I add grid without header. Maybe it's not the best desicion, but it works

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you are sure that each year row will include two (and always two) rows, you can use the datagrid without creating your own control. Instead of a DataGridTextColumn as the column, use a DataGridTemplate column, and use a StackPanel containing two TextBlocks (each in its Border) for each cell.

Comment: No, year row can include any number of rows.